# JavaScript. Доступ к свойству через скобочную запись при передачи названия свойств переменной

Tags: javascript

В JS есть замечательная возможность получить значение свойства объекта как через точечную нотацию (obj.prop) так и через скобочную (obj['prop'])

Условно у нас имеется следующий объект:

```
let object = {
    name: 'UserName',
    userProps: {
      age: 30,
      details: {
        city: 'London'
      }
    }
  };
```

Так же у нас есть метод, который принимает название свойства и новое значение и присваивает новое значение объекту:

```
const onChange = (propName, value) => {
    object[propName] = value;
  };
```

Все понятно для случая когда я передаю первым аргументом name, но что нужно передавать и как, чтобы заменить значение свойства city или age? Заранее благодарю.

```js
const object = {
  name: 'UserName',
  userProps: {
    age: 30,
    details: {
      city: 'London'
    }
  }
};
const onChange = (propName, value) => {
  object[propName] = value;
};

onChange('name', 'newName');
console.log(object);
```

Comment: скобочная нотация работает только с непосредственными ключами объекта, либо ключами в прототипе. Обратиться к свойству вложенного объекта - нельзя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'UserName',
  userProps: {
    age: 30,
    details: {
      city: 'London'
    }
  }
};
const onChange = (o, path, value) => {
  const props = path.split('.');
  for (let i = 0; i < props.length - 1; i++) {
    o = o[props[i]];
  }
  o[props[props.length - 1]] = value;
};

onChange(obj, 'name', 'newName');
onChange(obj, 'userProps.details.city', 'New York');
console.log(obj);
```

Проверки - самостоятельно.

Comment: А если используется TypeScript?

Comment: @makbeth Что - "если используется TypeScript"?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const object = {
  name: 'UserName',
  userProps: {
    age: 30,
    details: {
      city: 'London', 
    }, 
  }, 
};
const onChange = (...args) => {
  const [finalPropName, value] = args.splice(-2, 2); 
  args.reduce((obj, propName) => obj[propName])[finalPropName] = value;
};

onChange(object, 'userProps', 'age', 32);
onChange(object, 'userProps', 'details', 'city', 'Manchester');
console.log(object);
```

В первой строке функции извлекаем два последних аргумента (удаляя их из `args`), во второй - получаем последнее по вложенности объектное свойство, и присваиваем уже его свойству (имя которого извлекли из предпоследнего аргумента) новое значение (извлекли из последнего аргумента).
Как тут выполняется `reduce`: это по сути своей цикл по `args`, на первой итерации которого `obj` принимает значение первого элемента (в данном случае, `object`), а далее значение `obj` последовательно заменяется на `obj[propName]`, где `propName` содержит значение текущего элемента `args` (элементы перебираются в порядке их следования, конечно же).

---

Если хочется передавать путь к свойству строкой с разделителем-точкой, это можно так:

```
onChange(object, ...'userProps.details.city'.split('.'), 'Liverpool');
```

, но я не рекомендую так делать, т.к. вообще имена свойств могут содержать символ `.` (и тогда сплит по нему не сможет корректно разделить путь на фрагменты). Вместо этого, фрагменты пути можно сразу собирать в массив типа `['foo', 'bar.baz', 'qux']`, и деструктурировать его в аргументы.

Еще хочется сразу предостеречь от добавления проверок: в данной функции **не надо** их добавлять, потому что стандартным поведением JS при обращении к несуществующему свойству / несовместимости типов является бросание ошибки, и такое поведение ожидаемо - ему лучше соответствовать. Вызывающий код формирует аргументы, а значит и обработка ошибок (из-за них) является ответственностью именно вызывающей стороны:

```
try {
  onChange(/* .... */); 
} catch (err) {
  /* .... */
}
```

Comment: Можете привести пример работающей функции, которая принимает массив с последующей деструктуризацией?

Comment: @makbeth, могу, но разве есть смысл переписывать функцию вместо использования спред-оператора? То есть, чем не устраивает деструктуризация при вызове, `onChange(object, ...pathArr, newVal);` с имеющейся функцией?

Answer (score -1):

Или менять функцию `onChange` или так:

```
onChange('userProps',{
    age: 50,
    details: {
      city: 'Moscow'}
    });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]